# NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000] driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ubuntu-mate

Installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on a decade-old desktop. `lspci -k` shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

I wonder which `nvidia-*` driver package I need to install. I thought it should be something like `nvidia-96`, however as far as I checked, there is no `nvidia-96` package available.

Comment: The oldest driver in 16.04 is nvidia-173. Not sure if it supports GeForce4 MX 4000, it's a 2002 product after all.

Comment: You'll have to use the default open-source driver from now on. If it doesn't work then your hardware is obsolete by any objective standard.